# ffmpeg h264 crashes IE intermittently

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4

First for moderators, this is relevant because I have incorporated ffmpeg in a program to render videos needed for a web-app.

My problem is that the videos I render randomly crash IE 11. Other browsers are fine. Here is a sample of my encoding strings: (Execution of all the strings  presented renders two versions of one video)

```
ffmpeg -start_number 1 -framerate 23.98  -i C:\videos\imagesequences\GOPR2001\startfoot_%%04d.png -profile:v baseline -level:v 3 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 1  -preset ultrafast -vframes 30  -vf fps='fps=23.98' -y C:\sprites\GOPR2001\GOPR2001_concat_1.mp4

ffmpeg -start_number 52 -framerate 23.98  -i C:\videos\imagesequences\GOPR2001\%%04d.png  -profile:v baseline -level:v 3 -pix_fmt yuv420p  -crf 1  -preset ultrafast -vframes 80  -vf fps='fps=23.98' -y C:\sprites\GOPR2001\GOPR2001_concat_2.mp4

ffmpeg -start_number 110  -framerate 23.98  -i C:\videos\imagesequences\GOPR2001\endfoot_%%04d.png -profile:v baseline -level:v 3 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 1  -preset ultrafast -vframes 31  -vf fps='fps=23.98' -y C:\sprites\GOPR2001\GOPR2001_concat_3.mp4

ffmpeg -f concat -i C:\sprites\GOPR2001\concatlist.txt -profile:v baseline -level:v 3 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 28  -preset veryslow -y C:\sprites\GOPR2001\mobile_GOPR2001.mp4

ffmpeg -f concat -i C:\sprites\GOPR2001\concatlist.txt -profile:v high -level:v 4 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 22  -preset veryslow -y C:\sprites\GOPR2001\GOPR2001.mp4
```

Where of course the `concatlist.txt` file contains the list of the three previously generated files. (I do effects on the front and tail end of the video this way.) One concatenation is for a mobile version. Either version causes the problem in IE

Comment: Are the `vframes` switches for trimming the file?